# JS para manipular datas

Tags: javascript

como eu faço para criar um js que exiba os conteúdos do array conforme os dias da semana, tipo eu tenho o seguinte array:

```js
{
    "days": {
        "monday": [
            {"message": "Olá"}
        ],
        "tuesday": [
            {"message": "Seja bem vindo"}
           
        ]
    }
}
```

Quero saber se com js é possível eu exibir o conteúdo "monday" na segunda e "tuesday" na terça e assim por diante. É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o objeto Date você pode obter o dia da semana de acordo com a data, e com esta informações, você pode exibir uma mensagem personalizada. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript: Objeto Data</title>
  <script>
    var now  = new Date();        // Data atual
    var hrs  = now.getHours();    // 0 a 23
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var secs = now.getSeconds();
 
 
 var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";
var day = weekday[now.getDay()];


    document.writeln("<p>Data de Hoje: " + now + "</p>");
    document.writeln("<p>Hora: " + hrs + "</p>");
    document.writeln("<p>Minutos: " + mins + "</p>");
    document.writeln("<p>Segundos:" + secs + "</p>");
 document.writeln("<p>Hoje é " + day + "</p>");
    
 document.writeln("<h2>" + day  + "</h2>");
    
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me ajudou muito, obrigado!